# I have issues understanding the use of Numbas vectorize decorator in Python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numba

I am currently looking into the use of Numba to speed up my python software. I am entirely new to the concept and currently trying to learn the absolute basics. What I am stuck on for now is:

**I don't understand, what's the big benefit of the vectorize decorator**.

The documentation explains, that the decorator is used to turn a normal python function into a Numpy ufunc. From what I understand, the benefit of a ufunc is, that it can take numpy arrays (instead of scalars) and provide features such as broadcasting.

But all examples I can find online, can be just as easily solved without this decorator.

Take for instance, this example from the numba documentation.

```
@vectorize([float64(float64, float64)])
def f(x, y):
    return x + y
```

They claim, that now the function works like a numpy ufunc. But doesn't it anyways, even without the decorator? If I were to just run the following code:

```
def f(x,y):
    return x+y

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)

print(f(x,y))
```

That works just as fine. The function already takes arguments of type other than scalars.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 0):

Just read the docs few lines below :

> You might ask yourself, “why would I go through this instead of compiling a simple iteration loop using the @jit decorator?”. The answer is that NumPy ufuncs automatically get other features such as reduction, accumulation or broadcasting.

For example `f.reduce(arr)` will sum all the elements off `arr` at C speed, what `f` cannot.